# Looking for a simple system to showcase user-contributed artwork

Tags: open-source, file-management, cms, user-management

I am looking for a simple open-source online cms that allows users to upload and download files, in the spirit of [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/) or [Behance](https://www.behance.net/).

The use case is for collecting (and exhibiting) local artwork (photographs, texts) from my art class and friends.

What would you recommend?

- What kind of application are you looking for?

  - Something like an unsophisticated repository, somewhere in between a social network (e.g. [Elgg](https://elgg.org/)) and a library system (e.g. [Omeka with contribution plugin](https://omeka.org/classic/plugins/Contribution/)).
- What operating system do you want the application to run on?

  - Any (it will probably be hosted at DigitalOcean)
- What budget do you have?

  - Open-source only (I have some basic coding knowledge, i.e. I can read and follow instructions!)
- What features must the application have?

  - User contributions (incl. anonymous, i.e. simple file uploading)
  - File repository

Ideally:

- Versioning
- User profiles
- Comments...